# deploying snowflake tasks - from dev database to test database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have objects created in dev DB in snowflake. I have 1 pipe & multiple tasks in dev. how can I deploy the tasks to test/prod DB? is there any way to deploy all tasks in a single deployment?

Comment: Can you describe how you are splitting dev vs. test/prod?  Are they in different accounts, different databases, different schemas?  And can we assume there are roles that have permissions to both environments?

Comment: they are all in same accounts but under different databases. schema names remains same for all environmental databases.